# What is wrong with query? I am getting syntax error, but I cannot figure out anything that's wrong

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
db.haidb.find({
  "Provider ID": {
    "$exists": true
  },
  "Address": {
    "$exists": true
  },
  "City": {
    "$exists": true
  },
  "Measure ID": {
    "$regex": /^HAI_1.*SIR$/
  },
  {
    "$or": ["State": {
      "$regex": /^A/i
    }, "State": {
      "$regex": /^N/i
    }]
  },
  {
    "$and": [{
      "Compared to National": "Better than the National Benchmark"
    }, {
      "Score": {
        "$gte": 0.5
      }
    }]
  }
}).sort({
  "Hospital Name": 1.0
}).pretty()
```

This is what Mongo throws: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:153)

Please help!

Comment: This looks suspicious `  "$or": ["State": {`. reckon you're missing some braces around your or clauses.

Comment: Yes, just realized I missed it! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$or` and `$and` sections were not placed correctly.
This shall work.

```js
db.haidb.find({
  "Provider ID": {"$exists": true},
  "Address": {"$exists": true},
  "City": {"$exists": true},
  "Measure ID": {"$regex": /^HAI_1.*SIR$/},
  "$or": [
    {"State": {"$regex": /^A/i}},
    {"State": {"$regex": /^N/i}}
  ],
  "Compared to National": "Better than the National Benchmark",
  "Score": {"$gte": 0.5}
}).sort({
  "Hospital Name": 1.0
}).pretty()
```